# What happens in the browser before the actual functional tests are run

Tags: intern, leadfoot

When running Intern functional tests in the browser (not headless), I notice that a bunch of different things happen before the tests are actually run. Some things that happen are navigation to different pages, a dropdown with "foo" and "bar", and several other things. Once these finish, Intern then navigates to my webpage and runs the functional tests.

My question is, why does all this happen before the actual functional tests are run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality of a remote browser can be affected by the version of Selenium, the particular WebDriver server (e.g. chromedriver), the host OS, and proxies or other services being run on the remote host. Intern performs feature tests for the browser to determine what flavor of the WebDriver protocol it supports and what features (like mouse support) may be broken or have non-standard behaviors.

These tests are most useful for older browsers or web driver servers, and can often be disabled when current versions of everything are being used. You can disable these tests by specifying `"fixSessionCapabilities": false` or `"fixSessionCapabilities": "no-detect"` in your environment specifier.